# How do I disable auto-indent on Kakoune?

Tags: auto-indent, kakoune

I don't like text editors that perform auto-indentation in my code, because of various reasons, but [Kakoune](https://github.com/mawww/kakoune) seems to be hardcoded to do that? Is it possible to disable it?

I couldn't find any defined "hooks" for `indent`, just for `autocomplete`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run `:set global disabled_hooks .*-indent` in your Kakoune window or put

```
set global disabled_hooks .*-indent
```

in your `kakrc`.

Found the answer at https://github.com/mawww/kakoune/wiki/How-To#disable-auto-indentation, although it wasn't immediately clear what "disabled_hooks option" meant.

Answer (score 3):

It's not strictly an answer to your question, but I sometimes need to paste text into kakoune over an SSH session from Windows. In vim, I could do `:set paste`/`:set nopaste`.

In kakoune, I found I can enter insert mode with disabled hooks (see "Disabling Hooks" in https://discuss.kakoune.com/t/hooks/544) by typing in a `\` first, e.g. `\i`. Then I paste the text without indentation fuss and can leave insert mode again. Neat!

Comment: Although not strictly speaking an answer to the OP's question, this helped me A LOT just now. Thank you, thank you!